# Make the mode-line display percentage and not "Top/Bottom/All"

Tags: mode-line

[Mode line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html)'s [`%p`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html#g_t_0025_002dConstructs) displays the percentage of the current view of the buffer:

> %p The percentage of the buffer text above the top of window, or
>   ‘Top’, ‘Bottom’ or ‘All’. Note that the default mode line construct
>   truncates this to three characters.

I don't like the *Top/Bottom/All* and I'd like to always display the percentage. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm curious why. `Top` means 0%. `Bottom` means 100%. `All` means 100% and the top is visible too. You can do pretty much anything you like to the mode line, but in this case it would be a pain to monkey with this. Note that you can easily reverse the percentage direction - see [**`%P`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html) (instead of `%p`).

Comment: My brain will look for a number when I want to know where I am. When I have to occasionally remember that it could also be Top/Bottom, then I have to remember that.

Comment: One idea would be to calculate the buffer-size -- i.e., number of points -- between `point-min` and `window-start`, and `window-end` and `point-max`, and if so desired, the size of the visible buffer could be factored in -- i.e., points between `window-start` to `window-end` -- those calculations could be done in a blink of an eye and would not affect performance because point does not move.  Those buffer-size calculations could be turned into percentages.  I believe that this *is* an answer, but I'll let someone else write it up because I have other projects on my plate today.

Comment: Never really found it useful to know percentage of buffer above :\ IMHO knowing the current_line/total_lines, and eventually, knowing that ALL the content buffer is displayed (when I'm on the first line) is more useful. Just my opinion, maybe it's my experience which is not wide enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do something like this. Note,
however, that it displays exactly what you asked for (percentage of
text above the window), which is probably not what you actually want.
For instance, it never displays `100%`, since there will always be
some text inside the window.

```el
(setcar mode-line-position
        '(:eval (format "%3d%%" (/ (window-start) 0.01 (point-max)))))
```

You could also use `window-end`, which has the opposite disadvantage
(it almost never displays 0).

```el
(setcar mode-line-position
        '(:eval (format "%3d%%" (/ (window-end) 0.01 (point-max)))))
```

You may want to sorround these strings with spaces or some other padding.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in code for `%p` just looks at `window-start` and `point-max` and computes the percentage that way.  You can find this out using `C-h f format-mode-line` and then following the link to the Emacs C sources (assuming you have them around somewhere).

So, you can do this same thing using a `:eval` form in `mode-line-format`.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to provide the complete solution?